# R code for creating variable for accuracy/percentages

Tags: r

I am having some trouble with R code for a variable I am trying to add to my data frame. Essentially, participants responded to two classes of stimuli (A and B) and their responses could either be correct or incorrect. The important variables (columns) in my data set are: ID (participants' ID), stimtype (A or B), and response (correct or incorrect).

What I want to do is calculate, for each participant, create two "accuracy score" variables (columns): one where it lists accuracy percentage for stimulus type A, and one for  stimulus type B.

I can get those percentages fairly easily using table functions, but am having difficulty creating those variables in my dataset. Any advice very much appreciated, thank you!!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a data.frame `mydata` with character stimtypes and a TRUE/FALSE response, you can use

```
library(dplyr)
result <- mydata %>%
  group_by(ID, stimtype) %>%
  summarize(pct_response = 100 * mean(response, na.rm = T))
```

This interprets the logical responses (T/F) as 1/0 and taking the mean will give you the percentage for a given ID and stimtype. However, the result will have two rows per ID, with one for each stimtype. If you want the results in two columns, you can use `tidyr::spread`

```
library(tidyr)
result %>%
  spread(key = stimtype, value = pct_response)
```